# R - Keep reading line if 7 or more numbers are => 10

Tags: r, bash

I have a file `foo.txt` that looks like this:

```
7, 3, 5, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 7, 5, 5, 22, 18, 14, 23, 16, 18, 5, 13, 34, 24, 17, 50, 30, 42, 35, 29, 27, 52, 35, 44, 52, 36, 39, 25, 40, 50, 52, 40, 2, 52, 52, 31, 35, 30, 19, 32, 46, 50, 43, 36, 15, 21, 16, 36, 25, 7, 3, 5, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6
```

I want to read the numbers in sets of 15, moving to the right one number at the time:

```
7, 3, 5, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 7, 5, 5
```

then

```
3, 5, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 7, 5, 5, 22
```

and so on.

If 7 or more of those 15 numbers are =>10 then keep them in a growing object that ends when the condition isn't met. So the first one to keep would be

```
3, 3, 3, 6, 7, 5, 5, 22, 18, 14, 23, 16, 18, 5, 13
```

because 7 out of those 15 numbers are => 10 (those numbers are 22, 18, 14, 23, 16, 18 and 13

The output file would look like this:

```
3, 3, 3, 6, 7, 5, 5, 22, 18, 14, 23, 16, 18, 5, 13, 34, 24, 17, 50, 30, 42, 35, 29, 27, 52, 35, 44, 52, 36, 39, 25, 40, 50, 52, 40, 2, 52, 52, 31, 35, 30, 19, 32, 46, 50, 43, 36, 15, 21, 16, 36, 25, 7, 3, 5, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3
```

So far I'm stuck at getting sets of 15 digits but I don't know how to make the condition "7 or more must be => 10"

```
qual <- readLines("foo.txt", 1)
separados <- unlist(strsplit(qual, ", "))


    for (i in 1:length(qual)) {
        separados[(i):(i + 14)] -> numbers
```

I don't mind the language as long as it does the work

Comment: Looks like a task for `zoo::rollapply`. You might want to search SO for 'rollapply' to see worked examples

Comment: piggy backing for R `library(zoo); rollapply(x, 15, function(x) sum(x>10)>7)`

Comment: I think it's working, but the result of running: 
`fin<-(rollapply(separados, 15, function(separados) sum(separados>10)>7))`
`fin`
is a lot of "TRUE"

Comment: `separados[fin]` should give you the numbers you desire. (Double check to make sure the conditions are satisfied on the edge numbers, and the the excluded number near the edge)

Comment: It shows the complete set of numbers, not only the ones in `fin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added two `=`'s to [Vlo's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168425/r-keep-reading-line-if-7-or-more-numbers-are-10#comment39186131_25168425) and made this for you. Does this answer your question?

```
foo.txt <- c(7, 3, 5, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 7, 5, 5, 22, 18, 14, 23, 16, 18, 5,
             13, 34, 24, 17, 50, 30, 42, 35, 29, 27, 52, 35, 44, 52, 36, 39, 25, 40, 
             50, 52, 40, 2, 52, 52, 31, 35, 30, 19, 32, 46, 50, 43, 36, 15, 21, 16, 
             36, 25, 7, 3, 5, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6)

# install.packages(c("zoo"), dependencies = TRUE)
require(zoo)
bar <- rollapply(foo.txt, 15, function(x) sum(x >= 10 ) >= 7)

  (product <- foo.txt[bar])
   [1]  3  3  3  6  7  5  5 22 18 14 23 16 18  5 13 34 24 17 50 30 42 35 29 27
  [25] 52 35 44 52 36 39 25 40 50 52 40  2 52 52 31 35 30 19 32 46 50 43  3  3
  [49]  3  3  3  6
```

Comment: Works perfect! 
Thanks to Vlo and BondedDust too!

Comment: Is there a way to do the same but if `foo.txt` has more than one line? I mean to have the results for each line independently.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in Python (you said you don't mind the language):

```python
array = []
with open("foo.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        for num in line.strip().split(', '):
            array.append(int(num))

result = []
growing = False
while len(array) >= 15:
    if sum(1 for e in filter(lambda x: x>=10, array[:15])) >= 7:
        if growing:
            result.append(array[15])
        else:
            result.extend(array[:15])
        growing = True
    else:
        growing = False
    del(array[0])

print(str(result)[1:-1])
```

Short explanation: first `while` simply reads the lines in the file, strips end of line, separates every number between ", " characters and appends each number to `array`.

Second `while` checks the first 15 numbers in `array`; if they have at least 7 numbers >= 0, it appends all the numbers, or just the last one (depending if the last iteration), to `result`.  At the end of the loop, it removes the first number in `array` so that the loop can continue with the next 15 numbers.